# Can not figure out why this CSS Isn't working. I'm sure it's a simple mistake

Tags: css

I'm trying to take away a white border that is appearing from behind an image on my sidebar. I can't figure out what is causing the white border. I thought it was the padding, and then I thought it was the border. If you visit our home page (http://noahsdad.com/) and look on the side bar under the "new normal" picture you will see a "Reece's Rainbow" image. I'm trying to remove that white around the image. I pasted in the code below, but it's not doing anything. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
#text-23 { background: none}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason it's not working is the background: none is never getting to the img which has the background set on it (backgrounds don't cascade down they exist in the element and you can have multiple elements layered on top of each other much like a painting. Which has the effect of the background cascading)

```
#text-23 img { background: none; }
```

that should resolve your problems. I am assuming that when you call the class `textwidget` you still want it to append the white background, just not for this instance.  So if you set the above it will cascade properly with the correct specificity while leaving the rest of your page alone.

This can also be done by

```
#text-23 .textwidget img { background: none; }
```

but that level of specificity is not required.  However if you try to just do:

```
.textwidget img { background: none; }
```

this will override all of the instances where the background is set on an image in the `textwidget` container.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! I couldn't figure out what was going. I'm learning CSS so I appreciate you taking the time to explain what was happening. I'm trying to figure out what was overriding the background: none. As I look through my CSS the only thing I see with the background is )div.social_icon img {background: none;} That wouldn't be doing it, would it?

Comment: @RickSmith actually you were setting background: none on the container, but the container doesn't have a background and you don't have the backgrounds set to inherit so when you set background to none on the container it never cascaded down.  So it never got overridden. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain that. Very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have added the white border yourself by setting the following in line 884 of [style.css](http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/Standard/style.css):

```
.textwidget img {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 290px;   
}
```

Simply remove the background declaration. If you only want to remove this instance of a white border, add the following rule:

```
#text-23 .textwidget img {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the conflicting CSS class.

```
.textwidget img {
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 290px;
}
```

If you want to debug css you should really look into [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/)(a plugin for Firefox) or [Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) and use builtin dragonfly 
These allow you to rightclick on your HTML page and inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `style.css` file and search for `.textwidget img` and change the `background-color` property to `none`. It is currently set to `#FFFFFF` which is the hex color code for white and is resulting in the white border or background (precisely).

```
.textwidget img {
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't mind it being on some things (like the image above that one) I just didn't like it on that one image. I'm curious, why doesn't the white border pop up on the very first image?